# Properly use algorithm environment in latex/ overleaf

Tags: conditionals, overleaf, algorithms, comments, algorithmic

I am working with my old latex code, which at the time worked but now the output seems unexpected.

I am using the following packages:

```
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{algcompatible}
```

The output literally shows part of the code which is not desired. The code has comments that need to be shown.

The code is:

```
\BEGIN{ALGORITHM}[T]
\CAPTION{blabla}
\LABEL{blabla}
\BEGIN{ALGORITHMIC}[1]
\PROCEDURE{}{}
\STATE \TEXTBF{INPUT}: blabla, blabla, blabla, blabla $\MATHBB{blabla}$
\STATE \TEXTBF{OUTPUT}: blabla, blabla, blabla, blabla $\MATHBB{blabla}$
\STATE $N=LOG$    {\ALGORITHMICCOMMENT{\TINY ESTIMATION}}
\WHILE{$N$ DOES}
\STATE CONSTRUCT ALL 
\FOR{(ALL RANGE)}
\STATE CONSTRUCT 
\STATE IMPLEMENT OB
\STATE TRY 
\ENDFOR
\IF{($N$ DOES NOT C)}
\STATE $N=N+1$
\ENDIF 
\IF{($N$ CONV)}
\ENDIF 
\ENDWHILE
\ENDPROCEDURE
\PROCEDURE{}{}
\STATE \TEXTBF{INPUT}:}: blabla, blabla, blabla, blabla $\MATHBB{blabla}$
\STATE \TEXTBF{OUTPUT}: }: blabla, blabla, blabla, blabla $\MATHBB{blabla}$
\STATE ASSUME CHIP WIDTH AND CHIP HEIGHT    {\ALGORITHMICCOMMENT{\TINY INITIA}}
\WHILE{SOLUTION EXISTS}
\STATE CONSTRUCT
\FOR{(ALL RANGES)}
\STATE IMPLEMENT 
\STATE 
\ENDFOR
\IF{()}
\STATE $CHIP \;WIDTH=CHIP\;WIDTH-1$
\ENDIF 
\ENDWHILE
\ENDPROCEDURE
\END{ALGORITHMIC}
\END{ALGORITHM}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please show us a compilable TeX code resulting in your issue and please expliain what is unexpected ...

Comment: Hello. I don't understand what is meant by 'compatible' TeX code. 

Unexpected result is when I compile it in the overleaf I see:

ALGORITHM[T], {ALGORITHMIC}[1] in the output....

Comment: ...also line number is missing in the output..

Comment: "Compilable" (not "compatible") TeX code  mean that  the code "as is" should allow us reproduce the your isssue (and no other) without having to guess the missing parts and make a forensic reconstruction of the  document just to have some idea of the real issue (annoying and often impossible) . That is,  please post a complete document,  as minimal as possible (If the  issue remain *unaltered* after removing packages or contents, then please do not show us that part!)  but not some fragments.